# SLURM: Задача отменяется без причины при налиии 2x curl [JobState=CANCELLED Reason=None ExitCode=0:15]

Tags: curl

Slurm version: **slurm 19.05.5**

Здравствуйте!

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой отмены задачи в Slurm.
Задача автоматически отменяется (без описания причины) при наличии 2х curl в команде.

JobId=31938 JobName=test.slurm

UserId=enc(1001) GroupId=enc(1001) MCS_label=N/A
Priority=11900 Nice=600 Account=(null) QOS=(null)

**JobState=CANCELLED Reason=None Dependency=(null)
Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:15**

sbatch --get-user-env /home/enc/scripts/test.slurm

Запускаемый slurm script:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    #SBATCH --partition=transcoding_1
    #SBATCH --nodes=1
    #SBATCH --ntasks=1
    #SBATCH --output=taskID-606c6a782b92705c52e765ac_slurm-output-%j.out
    #SBATCH --error=taskID-606c6a782b92705c52e765ac_slurm-error-%j.out
    #SBATCH --constraint=encoding_qsv
    #SBATCH --nodelist=
    #SBATCH --nice=600
    #SBATCH --comment=TaskID:606c6a782b92705c52e765ac


    srun curl -d "taskId=606c6a782b92705c52e765ac&partNumber=0&totalParts=1&slurmJodId=$SLURM_JOB_ID&slurmNode=$(/bin/hostname)&quality=480" http://localhost:8081/slurm/encode/started/video

    srun curl -d "taskId=606c6a782b92705c52e765ac&partNumber=0&totalParts=1&slurmJodId=$SLURM_JOB_ID&slurmNode=$(/bin/hostname)&quality=480" http://localhost:8081/slurm/encode/started/video
```

С одним curl задача завершается успешно, с 2мя - падает.

Comment: Вы на StackOverflow на русском, здесь можно задавать вопросы только на русском языке.

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо за коментарий! Изменил язык вопроса на русский.